# Is "just-in-time calculation" an appropriate use for mutable?

Tags: c++, mutable, const-correctness

A graph can be represented as either an adjacency matrix or an adjacency list.   My `Graph` object represents the graph as an adjacency matrix.  For performance reasons, I don't calculate the adjacency list unless it is requested; however, once requested, I would like to retain the list (to avoid re-building it).

Is it appropriate to make the adjacency list `mutable`, so that users can generate the adjacency list for otherwise `const` `Graph` objects? I ask because I'm not convinced that building the adjacency matrix would be considered a "physical" as opposed to "logical" change to the state of the `Graph`. I also have an `adjacencyListBuilt` method, so the building of the adjacency list isn't "invisible" (see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#mutable-data-members).

If I understand correctly, declaring the `adjacencyList` instance variable `mutable` will allow *any* method to update it.  Is there a way whereby only the `buildAdjacencyList` method is able to modify the `adjacencyList` instance variable on a `const` object?

Comment: To your last question - well, just don't touch it in any other method. You are the author of the class, no one is twisting your arm to modify `adjacencyList` outside of `buildAdjacencyList`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `adjacencyListBuilt`? How is the caller expected to use this information? That sounds like exposing an implementation detail that should be irrelevant to the caller. Take that out, and using `mutable` for a member serving as a cache of the result of `getAdjacencyList()` becomes very reasonable.

Comment: `adjacencyListBuilt` is just used in `assert` statements.  Rather than checking whether the list has been built every time `getAdjacencyList` is called, I rely on the programmer to request it be build if needed.  (Yes, I know the benefits of removing this check are extremely small.)

Comment: Well, if you like the design where a) `const Graph` is usable, but b) its adjacency list is calculated on the fly on the first request and cached afterwards, then I'd get rid of public `buildAdjacencyList()` and have `getAdjacencyList()` calculate and cache it on the first call and return cached result on subsequent calls. If, after measuring the performance of this arrangement, you conclude that the "is list built" check in `getAdjacencyList()` is too expensive, then re-expose `buildAdjacencyList()` as a `const` method. It's weird, but sometimes we have to sacrifice purity for performace.

Answer (score 7):

Caching the results calculated from internal members using `mutable` is appropriate. Be aware that it can break the thread safety.

But I would also consider a separate class or function that performs a computation on a `const` object.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way whereby only the buildAdjacencyList method is able to modify the adjacencyList instance variable on a const object?

Sure, using a nested private member and `friend`:

```
class myGraph;
void buildAdjacencyListImpl(const myGraph&);

class myGraph
{
    class myAdjacencyListCache
    {
         mutable realAdjacencyList cached_list;

         friend void buildAdjacencyListImpl(const myGraph&);
    } adj_list;
    friend void buildAdjacencyListImpl(const myGraph&);

    void buildAdjacencyList() const { buildAdjacencyListImpl(*this); }
};

void buildAdjacencyListImpl( const myGraph& g )
{
    realAdjacencyList& listToBuild = g.adj_list.list_cache;
    // it isn't const, and can be modified
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Just-in-time calculation" is exactly what `mutable` was invented for, therefore yes, it is an appropriate use. Note that the interface would not specifically request building it; you'd just request *access* to it, and the class would notice that it wasn't yet built, and build it "behind the scenes". Therefore the logical state would *not* be affected.

If you are thinking of a function to request the building, and then a function or set of access functions that would be invalid to call when building was not yet requested, you are doing it wrong. Note that the problem then would be on the *interface* and not on the implementation; therefore it would be wrong no matter whether you implement it using `mutable` or not.

On your question of how to further protect it from other methods: If I understand you correctly, there are only two things that should ever be done to the adjacency list: Either it should be calculated from the current adjacency matrix, or it should be invalidated. Therefore I'd suggest to encapsulate it into a separate class (private to the `Graph` class) that encapsulates the mutable member (and is itself used as non-mutable member variable) and only offers two operations: (1) access the incidence matrix (const function, calculating the list if not yet calculated) and (2) invalidate the list (non-const, as only changes to the graph can make the list invalid). That way, no const member function of the `Graph` class can modify the list.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, in my particular case, there were so many different cached values that making things mutable got gross pretty fast. (The description above was simplified.)  Instead, I decided to make two different versions of `Graph`:  `ImmutableGraph` and `MutableGraph`.  `ImmutableGraph` has no methods to add or remove edges and vertices; thus, there are few cases where `ImmutableGraph` should be declared `const`.